# I have applied to work permit while staying as a student. What happens if my student visa is cancelled?

Tags: working-visas, student-visa, czech-republic

I came to Czech Republic to study and recently found a job. I have applied for a work permit and my application is received. Now, I am waiting for my work permit.

I have a contract signed by both parties (me, and the company) stating that I will start working as soon as I receive my work permit.
Thus, I can start at the company as an intern (without pay) immediately. This will be a great help to the process of orientation. 
However, by going to the workplace regularly means that I won't be able to attend the classes and my student visa will be cancelled.

I have declared that I will not stay in the country as a student anymore. Therefore, I would like to take this opportunity and accept to be an intern until my permit is issued.

Regardless of me working or not:
**If my student visa is cancelled when I am waiting for the work permit, does it have any effect on the process?**
Will I have to go back to my country? Or is it possible for me to wait here?

Comment: Do you currently have a long-term visa (put into your passport by an embassy, multiple entry, valid for up to one year), or a long-term residence permit (you get that in Czechia after single-entry visa in your passport)?

Comment: I have a long-term visa. Not the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Students are allowed to work in Czech Republic, so you can work for as long as your visa is valid. However as soon as its cancelled you will need to leave the country and wait for the work permit to be issued, no exceptions.

I would suggest playing everything by the book and waiting for your work permit to arrive.